# Multithreading Summation using Event

Tags: c++, multithreading, event-handling

I am trying to emphasize my knowledge in the Multi threading part and i have some issue in getting the event working well .

So basically the i am using two threads one thread is just setting a certain variable yy1 to one , the second thread should have a wait function to get the value of yy1 and add an extra value and put the result in variable y2 .

I can do it with Mutex or semaphore but struggling to use event with it.

```
    #include <process.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
void ThreadFunction1(void *pParam);
void ThreadFunction2(void *pParam);


HANDLE h_Event1;
int yy1= 0;
int y2 = 0;

void main(void)                             // Primary Thread
{
    h_Event1 = CreateEvent(NULL,            // Security Attributes
        FALSE,              // Manual Reset: no/auto , Auto Reset when the event released
        FALSE,              // Initial Statse: not set , not occupied 
        NULL);              // Name: no


    _beginthread(ThreadFunction1,           // Pointer to Thread Function
        0,                  // Stack Size set automatically
        (void*)&yy1);   // Frequency


    _beginthread(ThreadFunction2,           // Pointer to Thread Function
        0,                  // Stack Size set automatically
        (void*)&y2);    // Frequency

    SetEvent(h_Event1);
    CloseHandle(h_Event1);

    cout << yy1<<endl;
    cout << y2 << endl;

}

void ThreadFunction1(void *pParam)          // Secundary Thread
{
    int xx1;

    xx1 = (int)*(int*)pParam;

    WaitForSingleObject(h_Event1, INFINITE);
    xx1 = 1;
    *(int*)pParam = xx1;
    Sleep(100);
    _endthread();
}

void ThreadFunction2(void *pParam)          // Secundary Thread
{
    int xx1;

    xx1 = (int)*(int*)pParam;

    WaitForSingleObject(h_Event1, INFINITE);
    xx1 = 1+ (yy1);
    *(int*)pParam = xx1;
    Sleep(10);

    _endthread();
}
```

The Output is :

```
0
2
```

Note :
I know that it may make no sense to use multi threading in that case , but i'm just trying to get used on the Event usage.

Comment: Looks like `C++`. Tag your question with a proper language-specific tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the behaviour your asked for. You start your two threads, and both are waiting for the event. Than you signal event, they both wake up and start (in radom order) accessing global variable yy1. What you end up is completely undefined and erratic behaviour due to data race.

Comment: SergeyA, and how can i let the 2nd thread wait in the wait function until i get the result from the first result to achieve the proper summation ?

Comment: @OmarHussein, you should mutexes or mutex-like objects (like critical sections). Events are just not the right tool for this.

Comment: i get your point .. i was working on that code only to get familiar with events . i managed to make the code works also only by adding sleep() for 100 milliseconds before printing the result in the main method.